# viewWillAppear() stops working after segue and dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, viewwillappear

The storyboard of my iPhone app starts with a UITabBarController (three icons). From this controller there are three segues to one single UITableViewController (displaying weather data of three different weather stations). This target UITableViewController is configured in the UITabBarContoller's viewWillAppear().

When rotating the device to landscape I automatically segue to a third ViewController (with a UIScrollView on it for displaying a webcam). When rotating back to portrait, this UIViewController (with the scrollView) gets dismissed.

The behavior of my app is as follows:

**Szenario 1:**
The app starts on the first tab. When I do not rotate the device, then when choosing a new tab in the tab bar, the method viewWillAppear() is called in the target viewController.

**Szenario 2:**
The app starts on the first tab. I rotate the device (--> segue), rotate back (--> dismiss). When now choosing a new tab, viewWillAppear() is NOT called in the target viewController.

**Is there a reason why the iOS stops to call viewWillAppear() after the additional segue (and dismiss) happened? And is there a way to get around this issue?**

Comment: There's no such thing as a `UIScrollViewController`. There's a `UIViewController`, and a `UIScrollView`, but there is no Apple-defined `UIScrollViewController`. You could create such a class yourself, but I would advise against naming it that since that naming style strongly suggests that it's an Apple class.

Comment: The `viewWillAppear` method called every time.

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks for making me aware! It‘s of course a generic UIViewController with a scrollView on it. I corrected this in the question text now.

Comment: @Mannopson Unfortunately the viewWillAppear method is not called. None of my breakpoints gets hit and the print() to console doesn‘t print anything.

Comment: Now I was able to work around this issue: I changed the segue style from "present modally" to "show (e.g. push)". After dismissing the last UIViewController, the viewWillAppear method on the initial Controller gets called now. Any idea why "present modally" doesn't work?